# Xpath count function clarification

Tags: xpath, count

I would like to know why the following Xpath expression is give count as 2, instead of 3. Thanks for your help.

Xpath-

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(//x[1]/y[1])"/>
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test>
    <x a="1">
      <x a="2">
        <x>
          <y>y31</y>
          <y>y32</y>
        </x>
      </x>
    </x>
    <x a="1">
      <x a="2">
        <y>y21</y>
        <y>y22</y>
      </x>
    </x>
    <x a="1">
      <y>y11</y>
      <y>y12</y>
    </x>
    <x>
      <y>y03</y>
      <y>y04</y>
    </x>
</test>

//count (//x[1]/y[1]) is selecting the following 2 elements.

1) <x>
      <y>y31</y>

2) <x a="2">
        <y>y21</y>
```

and it is not selecting one of following elements in the same level, to add count as 3. I would like to clarify this.

```
<x a="1">
      <y>y11</y>


      or 

    <x>
      <y>y03</y>
```

thanks,
Mathew

Answer (score 0):

`//x[1]/y[1]` selects `y` elements that are 1st children of `x` elements that are 1 children or their parent.

so 1st child of `test`

```
<x a="1">
  <x a="2">       <!-- x is first child of its parent -->
    <y>y21</y>    <!-- y is first child of its parent x -->
    <y>y22</y>
  </x>
</x>
```

and 2nd child or `test`

```
<x a="1">
  <x a="2">
    <x>            <!-- x is first child of its parent -->
      <y>y31</y>   <!-- y is first child of its parent x -->
      <y>y32</y>
    </x>
  </x>
</x>
```

both are or contain a `x` element that itself has an `x` element as 1st child with `y` as 1st child, that is therefore matched.

but

```
<x a="1">          <!-- x is 3rd child of its parent test -->
      <y>y11</y>
      ...
```

is the 3rd child of `test`

```
<x>               <!-- x is 4th child of its parent test -->
      <y>y03</y>
```

is the 4th child of `test`

so they won't match

Comment: Thanks for your answer Paul, Would like to know why it matchs the second child x also  (since it already matched the first x child) 
Second x child matched
 <x a="1">
      <x a="2">
        <y>y21</y>

Comment: Added a comment on why the 2 `x/y` match

Comment: Thank you very much Paul. Appreciate your help.